# object has no method error using feedback.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery script feedback.js (found here https://github.com/ivoviz/feedback).

I've pretty much copied and pasted the Usage example and changed the links to point to the correct location. I also replaced all $ with jQuery for compatibility. However, I get the error in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {       // The
>   jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
>         return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );     } has
>   no method 'feedback'

I've been doing research but cannot figure out what I need to do to get this to find the feedback method it says it cannot find. I see feedback.js in the resources folder and the link to it is correct. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Head of HTML
<script src="js/feedback.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/feedback.min.css" />

//loaded in external .js file
jQuery.feedback({
    ajaxURL: 'http://test.url.com/feedback',
    html2canvasURL: 'js/html2canvas.js'
});
```

jQuery is loading in the order of, jQuery then feedback. So the order is correct.

Comment: Did you have the file in the js directory? (feedback.js) See if a 404 error is not thrown in the page..

Comment: As John said, anytime you get a function not defined/has no method - right click the page and view source. Now, click on the path to the javascript file(s) you're linking to and see if the paths you specified are valid (if the files are found).

Comment: I'm not getting any 404 errors. I'm also not getting any other errors complaining about feedback.js. The only other error in the console is for jQuery-UI, but it doesn't use jQuery-UI so that shouldn't effect it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder let me try that. It is loaded by a different part of the page, so that may be it.

Comment: This is the classic situation where you need to create a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org), because 99% of the time, you'll figure out the problem doing that, and the other 1%, you have something *replicable* that you can use to ask for help.

Comment: As things have happened in the meantime, I'll just repeat my suggestion about a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did a simple 2 div page and it works perfectly. It must be something else causing the issue. I'll have to dig in deeper. Thank you for taking time to assist me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was older versions of jQuery being used. I updated jQuery / jQuery UI to the latest versions. The problem then persisted due to another script using removed jQuery syntax. Using the jQuery migrate file fixed all errors and allowed all the scripts to load properly.